how to convert panda date time to particular date format and then extract substring out of it
I have this date time column in panda. I am converting it to specific date format. i want to convert this date into string and extract the substring out of it. I am finding it hard to do it. does anyone know how.
data in my datetime column looks like follows:
2024-01-30 13:45:00
2024-01-30 14:45:00
2024-01-30 15:45:00

I have converted it to date column using following statement:
da['date1'] = da['timestamp'].dt.strftime("%y%b%d")

Now my data looks like following:
24Jan30
24Jan30
24Jan30

Note this is in date format.
I want to extract year and month and from it. for that i have to convert it into string which is not giving me expected results.
expected output:
24Jan
24Jan
24Jan

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Are you familiar with string slicing ?

You can just remove the %d (day of the month) at the end of your statement, like this:
da['date1'] = da['timestamp'].dt.strftime("%y%b")
%y: year without century
%b: 3-letter abbreviation of month name

If you want to extract the substring out of the date, you can use the following. It matches a sequence of 2 digits (corresponding to %y) followed by exactly 3 letters (corresponding to %b):
df['year_month'] = df['date1'].apply(lambda x: re.match(r'\d{2}[A-Za-z]{3}', x).group())


Quote from op "i want to convert this date into string and extract the substring out of it" What you propose is to alter the 'date1' Series. Why this "answer" has been accepted is a mystery

Oh yep. Well there's another way of doing this. Of course, you could use [:5] to slice the first 5 chars (as you suggested in your comment). I'm editing my answer with another solution.

@SIGHUP Thanks for having pointed this out, I added the other solution.
